# How to create new variable from multiple conditions and a nested weighted average

Tags: r

I have a dataset that shows a value I'm interested in by date, age group and area code. I am not interested in the area code data, so I would like to create a time series that averages all values on a particular date from all area codes. This average needs to be weighted, as I have population by area code and the value.

The new data would just show the value on a particular data, by age group but show a national picture. Essentially, I want to do a complicated sumif (Excel speak) that sums all values if they match a specific age group and date, for multiple dates. I want to embed a weighted average formula within that.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I suggest you to check out the dplyr package and the function `group_by` and `summarize`.  Something along the lines `data %>% group_by(date, areaCode) %>% summarize(weighted.mean(value, population))`.  But as RS said, it is hard to tell unless we know more...